# gem install compass fails, can't download data from rubygems

Tags: rubygems, compass-sass

I'm trying to install compass on my Mac, on my home network, no proxy server.
but I just can't get it to work...

curl to the addresses below works for me..

Any advice?

Here's the command and result from terminal:

```
sudo gem install compass --verbose
Password:
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
connection reset after 1 requests, retrying
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
connection reset after 1 requests, retrying
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - too many connection resets (http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
GET http://rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
connection reset after 2 requests, retrying
GET http://rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
connection reset after 2 requests, retrying
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
connection reset after 1 requests, retrying
GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
connection reset after 2 requests, retrying
GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: compass
```

Comment: Wait a couple minutes, then try again. Sometimes Rubygems throws a little error for a minute or two. If you still can't install, try to `ping` the Rubygems server for a couple minutes. **EDIT:** what version is your Rubygems? It might not be up to date.

Comment: **I SOLVED TO PROBLEM!!!** the guy that I bought the Mac from decided to install an AntiVirus (avast), and it seems like it blocked only gem install calls.. CRAZY!

Comment: Must of mistook rubygems.org for being a malicious site... weird.

Comment: Anyone else looking for this, try disabling your anti-virus for a while, that did it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue on a mid-2012 MacBook Air. I had tried many other workarounds including updating gem manually. After reading Amir Mimran's comment above, I disabled Avast shields and my gem installation succeeded.

Prior to that I was getting the "too many connection resets" error. Now I need to figure out how to whitelist rubygems.org in Avast.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Comment: It worked for me! You can whitelist in Avast preferences -> Web Shield -> Advanced.

Comment: Spent too many hours on this Avast was the problem all along. Just disabled the web shield.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had this same issue while trying to gem install rails and following Amir Mimran's initial comment on Avast and going ahead and disabling the Web shield worked for me.

To disable the web shield, open up Avast, go into the preferences and disable the Web Shield and try your gem again. dmayo3's comment for adding rubygems.org to the whitelist is an option but this did not work for me but I suspect this may be because of all the 302 Temporarily Moved redirects that I encountered while running the gem install.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a proxy, do this:

```
gem install <gem_which_I_wanted> --http-proxy http://<proxy_adress_or_IP>:<proxy_port>
```

Replace thingis inside < and > to what you need.