# gem update not working when trying to update RubyGems from 1.3.6

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I am getting the following error message in the terminal when I attempt to update RubyGems from 1.3.6:

```
FitValet-MacBook-Pro:~ fitvalet$ rbenv -v
rbenv 0.4.0-51-ga2adc61    
FitValet-MacBook-Pro:~ fitvalet$ sudo gem update --system
Password:
Updating RubyGems
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
timed out (http://rubygems.org/yaml)
```

I also tried this and got the following error:

```
FitValet-MacBook-Pro:~ fitvalet$ gem install rubygems-update
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  could not find gem rubygems-update locally or in a repository
```

I've looked through various answers - many are talking about a proxy server or something as in this one: [How do I update Ruby Gems from behind a Proxy (ISA-NTLM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm). I asked a friend and he said this was not the issue, that my settings should be fine on the network.

Any ideas on how to update this would be tremendous, thank you!

Comment: Can you get to that URL? What about installing a newer version of Ruby with `rbenv` which should come with a more up-to-date version of `rubygems` bundled with it?

Comment: Yes - can get to the URL http://rubygems.org/. Do you think reinstalling is the best solution to the problem? I am new to terminal, how would I do that? I'm surprised that I don't have the most recent version of rbenv because I just installed that one step before this one :). Is there a way to simply update it? Thank you!

Comment: do you have access to rubygems.org for instance using curl or wget?

Comment: @rogerdpack I am not sure how to test, but I typed $ curl rubygems.org # and received lots of html in the terminal so think the answer is yes.

Comment: I wouldn't trust such a dusty, old version of rubygems to be able to update itself, I don't think that upgrade path is supported any longer. Build a new Ruby 1.9.3 or 2.0.0 and go from there.

Comment: you could try installing a newer rubygems from its .tar.gz distro file...

Comment: OK, so I just updated to 1.9.3 and then manually updated rubygems by @rogerdpack's instructions. But now I'm still getting this error: 
`FitValet-MacBook-Pro:~ fitvalet$ sudo gem install compass
Password:
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
`
It's the same error - any thoughts here?

Comment: you're able to download this file: http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz ?

Comment: @rogerdpack thank you for your help, figured this out. It was amazingly frustrating and had to spend hours searching for someone who had done the same stupid thing installing Avast!, would love to know how I might have diagnosed something like this more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY figured this out. I found this post [gem install compass fails, can't download data from rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156797/gem-install-compass-failes-cant-download-data-from-rubygems) and had the same problem - Avast! antivirus software was keeping me from accessing rubygems.org through the terminal to download, even though when I pinged the server it would work fine.

I went into avast! preferences and un-enabled the shields, and the install went through.